# Homework policy

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, homework-and-exercises

My main issue with how the site deals with 'homework questions' is about assumptions. I am an A level physics student and I never ask homework questions on this site. However I will ask questions about things I am struggling to understand. However these questions are often about basic things I need a greater understanding of but because these are basic questions people instantly assume it's a homework question and there for I get the old 'this isn't a homework help site' and then a homework tag is added, etc. When my question wasn't a homework question but purely a question most on this website would see as basic.

This could potentially drive away people such as myself who are learning physics at not an advanced level but still would like to ask genuine physics questions on SE.

There is lot's of talk on meta about how the 'quality' of questions must be improved which makes it sound like we're trying to push the site into an elitist form where a question has to be a certain level of complexity to be deemed 'high quality'

Comment: So... what are you actually asking? (Also, some examples of the kinds of questions you're talking about would probably help)

Comment: Please note that we use the word "homework" to refer to any question which asks for a specific calculation to be done. We know this is confusing and we're working on rewording the rules to get rid of the word "homework".

Comment: Totally agree! I always did my best when posting a question, but I still got "homework like" sometimes. I don't know why this question got so many downvotes. This culture is toxic.

Comment: The canonical question is *[How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)*.

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand why you are complaining. I looked at your account. You have only two questions, and both are not on hold *and* they are answered! Not only that, both *are* homework questions. Before you yell at me for being prejudiced too, please let me explain real quick.

Both of your questions are looking for answers that are sort of "calculate for me, do my work for me" questions. It doesn't matter whether or not they are actually homework, it is about the type of question they are: "do my work" type problems (which is why we are trying to reformulate the policy, because the close reasons aren't as clear as we'd like). That is why people are asking you to read the homework policy.

Finally, I'm not sure you've quite been on this site long enough to see what sometimes comes up. We get questions saying stuff like "solve this problem" with nothing of their own work. Once, we got a question asking for users to come up with "new and innovative ideas" for a project for school. We get some pretty bad questions. When we say on meta "improve quality of questions" we mean trying to make it more clear that that stuff is not allowed.

It's not about being elitist, or forbidding basic questions. Actually, some of the most upvoted questions might be considered "basic" by a good number of users on this site. Further, some of my questions have been well-upvoted, not closed, and answered, but they've been kind of basic sorts of questions. So the whole elitist thing isn't true at all.

So please, don't go off making accusations without actually considering what is going on. I hope that makes sense, and I hope your future on this site is a tad more pleasant.

---

At DanielSank's request, here are two questions I've asked that in my mind are simple (especially in their respective areas of physics) questions which are both upvoted and answered. In fact, the first one got 27 upvotes (!) which surprised me.

- [Why ket and bra notation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282286/why-ket-and-bra-notation)
- [Boltzmann formulation of entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274558/boltzmann-formulation-of-entropy)

Comment: Heather, this is a nice answer. It would be even better with some links to examples of your good but basic questions.

Comment: I don't think the two questions asked by OP is "calculate for me, do my work for me". You make this comment on your subjective opinion. I think OP was arguing this site intends to mark a question "doesn't spend enough affort before posting", and intends to assume someone's aurgement about their situation in real world is fake. Before coming PhysE, I was a software engineer who graduated from computer science. I didn't feel this kind of frustration when using Stackoverflow which is a parent of PhysE.